# HashSet contains

Tags: java, performance

I have set of keywords and I have one string  which contains keyword instances separated by '/'. e.g. 'Food' or 'Car' are keywords and '/food/oatmeal/fruits'  , '/tyre/car/wheel' are strings. Total # of keywords are 5500 . I need to flag this string 'eligible' if it has at least one of the 5550 keywords in it. One way I can do is to load all 5500 keywords in hashSet and split String in to tokens and check if hashSet contains each of the tokens. If find match, I flag that String 'eligible'.

Performance wise, Can there be a better solution ?

Comment: Do you have any code to show us,?

Comment: I am about to write a code but just wanted to do it with best approach. Isn't it clear in the question what approach I am thinking of? If not, I can  explain it in better way ..

Comment: You write "total # of string is 1 . I need to flag this string 'eligible' if it has at least one of the 5550 keywords in it." Are you talking about the same string here?

Comment: You are thinking right. With performance, it depends on which implementation of HashSet you actually use. Also you dont need to search for all tokens, once a token matches you can mark it as eligible.

Comment: Why worry about alternative solutions? When implemented, does it work? Is it 'fast enough'? To quote Donald Knuth: `premature optimization is the root of all evil`

Comment: @MartinMJ Yes, you are right. I am talking about the same string here. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Also with all due respect 5500 isn't that big a number. Even if you do it in O(n^2) it won't take more than a few seconds.

Comment: @Benjy Kessle What if the String  I am talking about  is a part of an object and I have millions of objects to process ?

Comment: If you have a fixed dictionary and a variable input - the [Aho–Corasick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm) algorithm is a good choice.

Comment: @copeg You might be right. I might be overthinking on this. Just don't want to miss any innovative solution which I am not aware of. Thanks

Comment: +1 to @pangin's recommendation of Aho Corasick. See also the answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14233470 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28254643

Comment: I would say it depends how a keyword matches the string. If a keyword matches only complete tokens and not parts, e.g keyword `car` matches only `/car/` but not `/cart/` nor `/sidecar/` nor `/scary/`, then tokenize the string and check if the `HashSet` contains the token would be the better approach. Assuming you only need to know if at least one keyword is in the string, but don't need to know how many and which ones in total.

Answer (score 0):

A simplified solution for token matching could be

```
public class REPL {

    private static final HashSet<String> keyWords = new HashSet<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        keyWords.add("food");
        keyWords.add("car");

        String[] strings = {
            "/food/oatmeal/fruits",
            "/tyre/car/wheel",
            "/steel/nuts/bolts",
            "/cart/handle/grill"
        };

        for (String s : strings) {
            System.out.printf("string: %-20s  ", s);
            if (isEligible(s)) {
                System.out.println("eligible: true");
            } else {
                System.out.println("eligible: false");
            }
        }
    }

    private static boolean isEligible(String s) {
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s, "/");
        while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
            if (keyWords.contains(st.nextToken())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```